# Trouble performing row count on results show in a list box

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, userform

I have one last problem with my user form with excel 2013 vba.

I want to perform a count on the number of rows (results) show in the search results box (SearchResultsListBox) on my userform when the Search button (SearchButton) is clicked.

The number of rows (results) counted should be displayed as a number in Results found box (ResultsFoundTextBox).

At the moment regardless of the number of rows (results) in the search results box, a number of 96 is always returned. Not sure why as the raw data currently only has 17-20 rows at most.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()
'dim the variables
Dim Crit As Range
Dim FindMe As Range
Dim SearchMe As Range
Dim the_sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim the_sheet3 As Worksheet

'error handler
On Error GoTo errHandler:

'set object variables
Set the_sheet1 = Sheets("Data Sheet")
Set the_sheet3 = Sheets("Filter Data")

'hold in memory and stop screen flicker
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'if All Columns is selected
With Me.SearchComboBox
If .ListIndex <> -1 Then
Select Case .Value
Case "All"
    the_sheet3.Range("Y2") = ""
    the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value

'if other categories are selected
Case "Project Name", "Client", "Sector", "Status", "Contract Value", "Anticipated Final Account", "Revenue Traded Prior", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "Discipline", "Board Director", "Associate Director", "Commercial Manager", "Project Manager", "Quantity Surveyor", "Pre-Con Start Date", "Actual Start Date", "Defect Period Start Date", "Defect Period End Date"
    the_sheet3.Range("Y2") = Me.SearchComboBox.Value
    the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
End Select
End If
End With

'find the value in the column
Set SearchMe = Sheets("Filter Data").Range("Y3")
Set FindMe = Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("A2:V62").Find(What:=SearchMe, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)
Sheets("Filter Data").Range("Y2").Value = Cells(2, FindMe.Column)

Sheets("Data Sheet").Range("A1:V62").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Range("'Filter Data'!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range( _
    "'Filter Data'!Extract"), Unique:=False

'variable for criteria header
Set Crit = the_sheet3.Cells(2, FindMe.Column)

'if no criteria is added to the search
If Me.EnterTextBox.Value = "" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = ""
Else
'add values from the search
the_sheet3.Range("Y2") = Crit
If Crit = "Project Name" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Client" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Sector" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Status" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Contract Value" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "Anticipated Final Account" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "Revenue Traded Prior" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "2015" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "2016" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "2017" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "2018" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "2019" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "Discipline" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Board Director" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Associate Director" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Commercial Manager" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Project Manager" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Quantity Surveyor" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = "*" & Me.EnterTextBox.Value & "*"
If Crit = "Pre-Con Start Date" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "Actual Start Date" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "Defect Period Start Date" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
If Crit = "Defect Period End Date" Then
the_sheet3.Range("Y3") = Me.EnterTextBox.Value
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If

'unprotect all sheets
'Unprotect_All

'add the dynamic data to the listbox
Me.SearchResultListBox.RowSource = Range("'Filter Data'!Extract").Address(external:=True)

'Number of results found
Me.ResultsFoundTextBox.Value = Me.SearchResultListBox.ListCount

'protect all sheets
'Protect_All

'error handler
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
errHandler:

'if error occurs then show me exactly where the error occurs
MsgBox "No match found for " & EnterTextBox.Text

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

I realise it is probably this line that it is a problem, but I have tried so many alternatives and none seem to work:

```
'Number of results found
Me.ResultsFoundTextBox.Value = Me.SearchResultListBox.ListCount
```

Thanks all. Last bit and then I am done! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your If statements are layered improperly.  By placing all of the `If`s first and `End If`s later, you are nesting all of the statements.  Thus, when one statement in the sequence evaluates to False, the rest are never reached.  Given that you are checking the same value in every check, I would recommend rewriting this section with a Select Case...Case block (which will make the code much shorter and easier to read).

Comment: You could also use `ElseIf`.  Properly indenting your code helps find errors like this. Download [VBA Smart Indenter](https://www.add-ins.com/macro-products-for-Microsoft-Excel/how-to-indent-vba-code/how-to-indent-vba-code.htm) it's free and it'll save you hours of formatting.